# Maven Building eclipse-gov.redhawk.core, nxm-ui repo

Tags: redhawksdr

This question is a follow up to Netrunner's question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19776547/3379929) Based on Eric Englund's response, I was able to get mil.jpeojtrs.sca packaged and installed by creating my own OSGi bundle of jacorb, installing it locally, and updating the pom.xml file in mil.jpeojtrs.sca/releng accordingly.

However, the same issue Netrunner brings up occurs when trying to install gov.redhawk.core... the nxm-ui repo points to a redhawk.sdr.org repo:

```
http://download.redhawksdr.org/nxm-rcp/releases/1.0
```

Unlike jacorb, I can't find an equivalent package to bundle. As Netrunner asked, is this a unique, REDHAWK developed package? If so, could it be made accessible on github, so that we can also build our own bundle if necessary? If not, could you point us toward an equivalent package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE can be built from source however it currently requires a bit of leg work.  Here are the steps you can take and a script to automate the process.  This is just an example and should be modified to fit your need.

1. There are a number of plugins that you'll need to create an update site for, using the REDHAWK 1.9.0 IDE it's fairly easy.

   - Open your 1.9.0 IDE.  File -> New -> Project.  Select the Show All Wizards checkbox.  Type in "update" to filter to the "Update Site Project"
   - You may be prompted to enable development of plugin projects, hit okay.
   - Give the project a name & click finish.
   - Add a category, provide an ID & name doesn't matter what but it is required.
   - Now add the following features:

   --- org.jacorb - Not packaged as an update site on the internet anywhere

   --- org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.xviewer.feature - This is only because the nebula feature does not have stable API and have changed since the build of 1.9.0

   --- org.python.pydev.feature - Pydev API has also changed since the build of 1.9.0

   - Click Build All.  Copy down the location of this update site.  To find the location you can right click on site.xml and select properties.  The path needed is the folder which contains site.xml
2. Copy the script below, place it into an empty folder and change the LOCAL_P2 variable to point to this newly generated P2 Site.
3. make the script executable using chmod +x
4. Run the script.  This may take a while but it will clone all of the repositories, make the proper patches and build the IDE Product.

Again, this should serve simply as an example and not as a build system for the IDE.  Also note that this is building 1.9.0 and modifications would be necessary to build the develop-1.10 and the develo-1.9 branches of the IDE.

```
#!/bin/bash

function error() {
        printf "\n\nREDHAWK IDE BUILD Failed!\n\n"
        exit 1
}

LOCAL_P2="/home/ylb/exampleLocation"

MVN="mvn"
MVN_PHASE="clean verify"
GIT="git"
REDHAWK_VERSION="develop-1.9"
MINOR_VERSION="1.9.0"

BASEDIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

MIL_GIT="https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-mil.jpeojtrs.sca.git"
MIL_BRANCH=${REDHAWK_VERSION}
MIL_P2="-Dmil.jpeojtrs.sca=file:///${BASEDIR}/mil.jpeojtrs.sca/releng/p2/target/repository"

CORE_GIT="https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-gov.redhawk.core.git"
CORE_BRANCH=${REDHAWK_VERSION}
CORE_P2="-Dgov.redhawk.core=file:///${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.core/releng/core/p2/target/repository"
RCP_P2="-Dgov.redhawk.core.rcp=file:///${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.core/releng/rcp/p2/target/repository"

IDE_GIT="https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-gov.redhawk.ide.git"
IDE_BRANCH=${REDHAWK_VERSION}
IDE_P2="-Dgov.redhawk.ide=file:///${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.ide/releng/p2/target/repository"
DOC_ZIP="-Dgov.redhawk.ide.help.doc.zip=file:///${BASEDIR}/doc.zip"

CODEGEN_GIT="https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-gov.redhawk.codegen.git"
CODEGEN_BRANCH=${REDHAWK_VERSION}
CODEGEN_P2="-Dgov.redhawk.codegen=file:///${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.codegen/releng/p2/target/repository"

PRODUCT_GIT="https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/eclipse-products-gov.redhawk.ide.product.git"
PRODUCT_BRANCH=${REDHAWK_VERSION}
PRODUCT_P2="-Dgov.redhawk.ide.product=file:///${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/p2/target/repository"

# First clone all the repositories
if [ ! -d mil.jpeojtrs.sca ]; then
  printf "\n\nCloning mil.jpeojtrs.sca...\n\n"
  ${GIT} clone -b ${MIL_BRANCH} ${MIL_GIT} mil.jpeojtrs.sca; cd mil.jpeojtrs.sca; git checkout ${MINOR_VERSION}; cd ..;
fi

if [ ! -d gov.redhawk.core ]; then
  printf "\n\nCloning gov.redhawk.core...\n\n"
  ${GIT} clone -b ${CORE_BRANCH} ${CORE_GIT} gov.redhawk.core; cd gov.redhawk.core; git checkout ${MINOR_VERSION}; cd ..;
fi


if [ ! -d gov.redhawk.ide ]; then
  printf "\n\nCloning gov.redhawk.ide...\n\n"
  ${GIT} clone -b ${IDE_BRANCH} ${IDE_GIT} gov.redhawk.ide; cd gov.redhawk.ide; git checkout ${MINOR_VERSION}; cd ..;
fi

if [ ! -d gov.redhawk.codegen ]; then
  printf "\n\nCloning gov.redhawk.codegen...\n\n"
  ${GIT} clone -b ${CODEGEN_BRANCH} ${CODEGEN_GIT} gov.redhawk.codegen; cd gov.redhawk.codegen; git checkout ${MINOR_VERSION}; cd ..;
fi

if [ ! -d gov.redhawk.ide.product ]; then
  printf "\n\nCloning gov.redhawk.ide.product...\n\n"
  ${GIT} clone -b ${PRODUCT_BRANCH} ${PRODUCT_GIT} gov.redhawk.ide.product; cd gov.redhawk.ide.product; git checkout ${MINOR_VERSION}; cd ..;
fi

# The documentation is wrapped up into the build, rather than build the documentation just create a dummy zip file
touch FakeDocumentation.txt
zip doc.zip FakeDocumentation.txt

# Now we must fix the pom.xml files to point to proper locations

# Fix things wrong with core
sed -i 's,http://download.redhawksdr.org/nxm-rcp/releases/1.0,http://nextmidas.techma.com/p2/nxm.ui/updates/latest,g' ./gov.redhawk.core/releng/pom.xml

# Now ide pom

# CAREFUL! Removing lines 33-45
if [ $(grep "<id>eclipse-updates</id>" ./gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml | wc -l) == 1 ]; then
  sed -i '33,45d' ./gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml
fi

sed -i '/<eclipse-support>/d' ./gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml
sed -i '/<eclipse-updates>/d' ./gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml
sed -i "s,http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot,file://${LOCAL_P2},g" ./gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml
sed -i 's,http://download.redhawksdr.org/nxm-rcp/releases/1.0,http://nextmidas.techma.com/p2/nxm.ui/updates/latest,g' ./gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml

# Now the codegen
sed -i 's,http://download.redhawksdr.org/nxm-rcp/releases/1.0,http://nextmidas.techma.com/p2/nxm.ui/updates/latest,g' ./gov.redhawk.codegen/releng/pom.xml
sed -i "s,http://pydev.org/updates,file://${LOCAL_P2},g" ./gov.redhawk.codegen/releng/pom.xml

# Now the product
sed -i "s,http://download.redhawksdr.org/mil.jpeojtrs.sca/releases/1.9,file://${BASEDIR}/mil.jpeojtrs.sca/releng/p2/target/repository,g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i 's,http://download.redhawksdr.org/nxm-ui/releases/1.0,http://nextmidas.techma.com/p2/nxm.ui/updates/latest,g' ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i "s,http://download.redhawksdr.org/gov.redhawk.codegen/releases/1.9,file://${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.codegen/releng/p2/target/repository,g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i "s,http://download.redhawksdr.org/gov.redhawk.core/rcp/releases/1.9,file://${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.core/releng/rcp/p2/target/repository,g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i "s,http://download.redhawksdr.org/jacorb/releases/3.1,file://${LOCAL_P2},g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i "s,http://download.redhawksdr.org/gov.redhawk.ide/releases/1.9,file://${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.ide/releng/p2/target/repository,g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i "s,http://download.redhawksdr.org/gov.redhawk.core/releases/1.9,file://${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.core/releng/core/p2/target/repository,g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target
sed -i "s,http://download.eclipse.org/technology/nebula/snapshot,file://${LOCAL_P2},g" ./gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/target-definition/target-definition.target

# Then build each repo.
printf "\n\nBuilding mil.jpeojtrs.sca...\n\n"
${MVN} -f ${BASEDIR}/mil.jpeojtrs.sca/releng/pom.xml ${MVN_PHASE} -Djacorb=file://${LOCAL_P2} ${MIL_P2} || error

printf "\n\nBuilding gov.redhawk.core...\n\n"
${MVN} -f ${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.core/releng/core/pom.xml ${MVN_PHASE} -Djacorb=file://${LOCAL_P2} ${MIL_P2} ${CORE_P2} || error

printf "\n\nBuilding gov.redhawk.rcp...\n\n"
${MVN} -f ${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.core/releng/rcp/pom.xml ${MVN_PHASE} -Djacorb=file://${LOCAL_P2} ${MIL_P2} ${CORE_P2} ${RCP_P2} || error

printf "\n\nBuilding gov.redhawk.ide...\n\n"
${MVN} -f ${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.ide/releng/pom.xml ${MVN_PHASE} -Djacorb=file://${LOCAL_P2} ${MIL_P2} ${CORE_P2} ${RCP_P2} ${DOC_ZIP} ${IDE_P2} || error

printf "\n\nBuilding gov.redhawk.codegen...\n\n"
${MVN} -f ${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.codegen/releng/pom.xml ${MVN_PHASE} -Djacorb=file://${LOCAL_P2} ${MIL_P2} ${CORE_P2} ${RCP_P2} ${IDE_P2} ${CODEGEN_P2} || error

printf "\n\nBuilding gov.redhawk.ide.product...\n\n"
${MVN} -f ${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/pom.xml ${MVN_PHASE} -Djacorb=file://${LOCAL_P2} ${MIL_P2} ${CORE_P2} ${RCP_P2} ${IDE_P2} ${CODEGEN_P2} ${PRODUCT_P2} || error

printf "\n\nBuild SUCCESS!!!\n"
printf "\n\nProducts may be found in ${BASEDIR}/gov.redhawk.ide.product/releng/product/target/products/gov.redhawk.product.ide.product\n"
```